# how to get complete value after multiplying 2 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I am having trouble with multiplying my numbers and getting not correct value.

I have numbers `1,2,3,6,12` and `2.95,3.95,6.95,15,95`

but when I multiply my number 3 with 2.95 using `2.95 * parseInt('3')` it returns `8.850000000000001`

and when I multiply 12 with 15.95 it returns 179.3999999999998.

I dont want this too long zeros and this kind of value .8500000000001

its also returns some of those numbers when they multiply.

how to get rid of this? how can I get complete value like `12 * 15.95` should give `179.40`

Comment: For JavaScript you can utilize `Math.round()` to do this. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round @Juhana No it's not, you didn't even read the question did you.

Comment: Although this question asks how to get rid of the effects rather than why this happens, it should still be marked as a duplicate of "Is floating point math broken?" because the answer is provided there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8633598/1248365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) (keep in mind this will return a string):

```
var myString = (12 * 15.95).toFixed(2);
//myString = "191.40"
```

Comment: That's literally it. But here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/83BZZ/

Comment: Well this is great, literally awesome :D

Comment: Remember to keep your significant digits in check. If you're multiplying 12.95 by 12.95, for example, you'll want to use `.toFixed(4)` instead of `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Expanding on @RiverTam you're probably not going to want to use `.toFixed()` until you are outputting the final result for display.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Jack's answer, which is also valid, you can just use [Math.round10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

To round to 2 decimal places, use `Math.round10(x, -2)`

For example:

```
var answer = Math.round10(12 * 15.95, -2);
```

This differs from Jack's answer in that it gives you the value as a number rather than as a string, saving a couple of keystrokes.